# Broken lists in IE9 and Opera

Tags: html, css, css-float, cross-browser

I've prepared this demo:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7224702/lists-bug.html

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE8 but is broken in Opera and IE9.

Oh and I don't want to use list-style-position: inside; because if some <li> is longer then one line the second line is not correctly indented.

Comment: +1 for the demo but for people without Opera/MSIE it would be nice if you could *describe* the error.

Comment: It's not so easy to describe and I don't think someone could solve it with mere description without actually seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little later then planned but here is my final solution.

1. Use list-style-position: inside;.
2. To repair the indenting of second and folowing lines, use negative text-indent (thanks Joey!)
3. It is not easy to determine the right value for the negative text indent as every browser does things little differently. Knowing that we will need to use something where we can set the width of the marker manually. And that something is pseudo-element :before. (thanks skip405!)
4. With the :before pseudo-element and right value of the content property we can now use list-style-type: none;
5. Delete the list-style-position from 1. as it's useless now.

You can see working demo here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7224702/lists-counters.html

The only drawback is with content: counter(list, disc); in Opera 12. The disc/circle/square values are not working as they sould, values like decimal are alright. I've already reported it as a bug so hopefully it'll be fixed in next version.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with lists that isn't really specified by CSS. It just says that the marker is outside the box but doesn't precisely specify where.

You could perhaps solve it with `text-indent` to move the first line back again.

Comment: Wow! I wasn't aware that text-indent property can have negative values as well. With this I probably can solve this issue. I'll post the solution tomorrow hopefully. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I didn't yet figure out how to reliably position the first line so that it lines up with subsequent ones. On IE it seemed to need a `text-intent` value of around `-1.3` but not quite.

Comment: For me -1em works fine in every browser except IE9. Anyway I probably can fix it using :before and counters instead. Didn't have time to try it yet though.

Answer (score 1):

That's the question that's been bothering me for some time as well.

First of all if we look at the spec describing the `list-style-position: outside` property we will see that

> "CSS 2.1 does not specify the precise location of the marker box or
>   its position in the painting order".

This actually makes this situation not a bug, merely different implementations.

IMO Opera and IE9 make it closer to the spec - which is to put the marker... well... outside the box. In case of floats the box made by the `li` element is still full-width, only content is shifted inside of it.

I tried to think of alternative solutions but they still turn out to be inappropriate and cause more problems than they solve. An example of using css3 [counter increment](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-counter-increment) can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/s3sZS/3/, but visually it looks like `list-style-position: inside` (your indentation problems remain) and the increment itself is selectable and copyable (at least in Opera).

Actually `list-style-position: inside` looks like the only appropriate solution to this imo.

If you are interested in future implementations of lists - you may read the [CSS Lists and Counters Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-lists/) (currently Editor's Draft).

Comment: I am aware about counters and I actually do use them from time to time. Anyway not exactly an answer to my question but you sure provided a very helpful analysis. I probably will combine counters with the text-indent solution mentioned above. Thanks! :-)

Comment: yes, the solution, proposed by Joey is definitely worth a try (I upvoted him myself :) ) The only problem left to tackle is the distance... because again - the distance between the marker and the text differs from browser to browser. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/QeZSK/1/) is made for Opera 12, works more or less correctly in Firefox, but fails in Chrome or IE - where results differ.